# What's the best way to index the entire ETH blockchain?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I'm trying to get all transaction/token data given an address. Right now I'm using the etherscan API which is fine but makes me dependent on 3rd party software as well as their requests/s limits. Is the only other alternative indexing all 900 gigs of the ETH chain into a local db (mysql or mongodb or something) and then writing queries?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You run your [own node](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513) and then [index it to a local database](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#advanced-example-fetching-all-token-transfer-events).